# Looking for nodejs library for stream behavior like Flash has

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a multiplayer game in Flash & Nodejs for the server (TCP).

In Flash there is this stream behavior where if you do example:
socket.readUnsignedByte() it will return the byte(s) from the stream from 0 position, and then it will get rid of it from the stream.

The stream is all the data that is being sent from server to Flash, and it stays there until I read it. I can read it bit by bit (not literally bit), whenever I feel like, and this is the behavior I want. I need to know how much data there is in the stream and be able to do things like readUnsignedInt().

For example I got:
0x01 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0a

and I do: .readUnsignedByte(), it will return the 0x01, and the stream will change to:
0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0a, and be reduced to the size of 4 bytes from 5 bytes.

So I'd be looking for something like stream.readUInt32();...

Is there any library to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though that's highly unperformant (rebuilding the buffer at every read), there's https://github.com/dcodeIO/ByteBuffer.js that do exactly that, it keeps the current OFFSET in the buffer, without getting rid of it, if you must signal do the GC to get rid of the Buffer.

For the stream itself, you can pipe the socket to a transform stream, so you can read then get rid of the data after you 'walked' through the chunk / buffer that were concatenated.